# How to change logo dynamically?

Tags: files

How can i change the logo on a site, dynamically, with a URL field which doesn't point to an actual image but to a rendering of an image.
Is this possible?
I've tried this:

```
$thisimage = $logo_img_url. "&file=" . $_SESSION[ 'logo_img' ] . "&width=300&height=80";
variable_set( 'logo', $thisimage );
```

but it's not working.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should echo the path to the theme logo, which you could wrap in an  tag:

```
<?php echo theme_get_setting('logo_path'); ?>
```

If you want to re-size, crop, or modify the image you should do that in an image style. Once you have made an image style in Configuration > Media > Image Styles, you can echo the logo with that style like so:

```
<?php echo image_style_url('my_style_name', theme_get_setting('logo_path')); ?>
```